# How do I match up two lists of data rows by identical column values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup, vba

I have two lists of data. I need to be able to link up each row into a new page/spreadsheet by the model number. Both documents should have each other's model numbers but I cannot organise them through custom sort.

Is there some way using VLOOKUP or similar formulas that I can achieve this?

[image: SO23675954 example]

The top is what I want the result to be like and below it is my two lists of data.

Comment: To make sure I completely understand: you want each model number to be on its own sheet? Based on your screenshot, that means you'll wind up with at least 20 sheets, which could be hard to manage. Will there be items in either list that don't have a match, or are they both totally complete?

Comment: Not onto new sheets. Just all of it onto one separate sheet. They aren't totally complete. The one one the left will have more than the one on the right.

Comment: Ok, that's a great start. How do you want to handle the items on the left sheet that don't have a match on the right sheet?

Comment: They can still be on this new sheet but just have them right at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you don't really need VBA for. You can use a `VLOOKUP()` or even better an `INDEX(MATCH())`

Supposing the following:

1. Sheet names are S1 and S2
2. Column A is "Model", column B is "Description", column C is "Price" for both sheets

You can do the following:

In cell S1!D2, add either of the following formulas:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'S2'!A:C,2,0)
=INDEX('S2'!B:B,MATCH(A2,'S2'!A:A,0),1)
```

In cell S1!E2, add either of the following formulas:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'S2'!A:C,3,0)
=INDEX('S2'!C:C,MATCH(A2,'S2'!A:A,0),1)
```

Drag the formulas down to the bottom. You can do the same on sheet S2. You can also build in error checking using `ISNA()` and `IF()` if you want.